# Why isn't my DropDownList binding to my model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework-6, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

ViewModel:

```
Public Class UserViewModel
<Display(Name:="Roles List")> _
Public ReadOnly Property AllRoles As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
    Get
        Dim dbContext As New AuthUserContext
        Dim roleQuery = (From r In dbContext.AuthRoleSet Select r Where r.isActive = True)
        Dim roles As IEnumerable(Of AuthRole) = roleQuery.ToList()
        Return roles.Select(Function(o) New SelectListItem() With {.Text = o.RoleName, .Value = o.AuthRoleID})
    End Get
End Property
Public Property User As New AuthUser
End Class
```

My AuthUser class:

```
Public Class AuthUser

'Properties
Public Property AuthUserID() As Integer

<Required()> _
<Display(Name:="User Name")> _
Public Property UserName() As String

<Required()> _
<Display(Name:="Current Roles")> _
Public Overridable Property AuthRoles As ICollection(Of AuthRole)

End Class

Public Class AuthRole
Public Property AuthRoleID() As Integer

<Required()> _
<Display(Name:="Role Name")> _
Public Property RoleName() As String

<Required()> _
<Display(Name:="Is Active")> _
Public Property isActive() As Boolean

Public Overridable Property AuthUser As ICollection(Of AuthUser)

End Class
```

My Get Controller:

```
Function CreateUser() As ActionResult
    Dim model As New UserViewModel
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

My Post Controller:

```
Function CreateUser(ByVal authuser As UserViewModel) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        db.AuthUserSet.Add(authuser.User)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If

    Return View(authuser)
End Function
```

My View:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()
@Html.ValidationSummary(True)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@<fieldset>
    <legend>AuthUser</legend>

   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.User.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.User.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.User.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.User.AuthRoles)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.User.AuthRoles, Model.AllRoles, "-- Select Role--")
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.User.AuthRoles)
    </div>

    @*Have to fill this is for ModelState validation - via jQuery*@
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.User.AuthRoles)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

Alright, what I'm doing here is reading all my available Roles into my ViewModel.  I want to list them as a dropdownlist, and use the AuthRoleID selected from there to determine which role to assign in my Model.

My AuthRoles property is always empty in my post.  My view does all display correctly.

I'm using EF6, Code First, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post comments yet but my first question would be the DropDownList? You are trying to bind ICollection(Of AuthRole) to a selected value of type int, you will only ever be able to select one value, not a list. You need a different control such as ListBox. However to select one role:

Add the property SelectedRole...

```
Public Class UserViewModel
<Display(Name:="Roles List")> _
Public ReadOnly Property AllRoles As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
    Get
        Dim dbContext As New AuthUserContext
        Dim roleQuery = (From r In dbContext.AuthRoleSet Select r Where r.isActive = True)
        Dim roles As IEnumerable(Of AuthRole) = roleQuery.ToList()
        Return roles.Select(Function(o) New SelectListItem() With {.Text = o.RoleName, .Value = o.AuthRoleID})
    End Get
End Property
Public Property SelectedRole As Integer //for the drop down list to bind selected value to//
Public Property UserName As String //all you need for the view model
Public Property UserId as String //hidden value in the view when you come to edit the user and post it back to the controller
End Class
```

In your view change the drop down list to:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.SelectedRole, Model.AllRoles, "-- Select Role--")
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.SelectedRole)
</div>
```

add this hidden field in the view:

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Id)
```

Your Create Get Method:

```
Function CreateUser() As ActionResult
    Dim model As New UserViewModel
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

Your Edit Get Method

```
Function EditUser(id as string) As ActionResult
    //logic to test if Id is empty if not fetch user from dB as variable user
    //Dim user as New AuthUser... etc
    Dim model As New UserViewModel
    model.SelectedRole = user.AuthRole // assuming one role as you are using DropDownList - you would need to use a different Editor to multi select roles and thus change the logic to get a list of roles
    model.UserName = user.UserName
    model.Id = user.Id
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

Then your Create Post controller you can set the role

```
Function CreateUser(ByVal model As UserViewModel) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        //logic to update role from authUser.SelectedRole
        Dim authuser As New AuthUser
        //update properties of authuser from the model
        authuser.UserName = model.UserName // etc.
        //
        db.AuthUserSet.Add(authuser.User)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If
//something went wrong
Return View(model)
End Function
```

for Edit Post method:

```
Function EditUser(ByVal model As UserViewModel) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        //logic to update role from authUser.SelectedRole
        //Fetch user from the dB using the hidden field model.Id
        //update properties of fetched user from the model
        authuser.UserName = model.UserName // etc.
        //

        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If
//something went wrong
Return View(model)
End Function
```

I haven't tested the above and am used to c# but hopefully you get the idea.

EDITED for ViewModel additions as per comments. You could create a seperate view for Create and Edit and thus seperate ViewModels - but essentially its good practice to ensure that the ViewModel is completely unaware of the entity and vice versa

Comment: That's close... the problem is, my AuthUser.AuthRole comes back empty to my ViewModel - so I get Model Errors.  The DropDownList binds to the SelectedRole just fine - but nothing ends up bound to AuthUser.AuthRole.  Specifically: {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'SAOCDR.AuthRole' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}  So maybe it's trying to bind the string value instead of the ID?

Comment: One more comment, in case it helps: AttemptedValue was "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[SAOCDR.AuthRole]"

Comment: Sorry my error, I didn't edit this code @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.User.AuthRoles) It should be @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.SelectedRole) I shall edit appropiately - you should make the SelectedRole Required not the AuthUser.AuthRole

Comment: Well actually you should make a ViewModel for the AuthUser rather than passing the entity in, that way you can keep the Required on the Entity, but in the AuthUserViewModel you would have SelectedRole as Required

Comment: Isn't that what my UserViewModel is?  Or am I misunderstanding ViewModels?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how the ViewModel should be disconnected completely from the Entity

Comment: That... Is pretty darn cool.  So I just use the properties I need from my Model in my ViewModel, and tie it all together in the controller?

Comment: Yup that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AuthRoles` property requires objects of type, `AuthRole`, whereas you're posting back a list of `Integer`. In other words, you can't post directly back to this collection property. Instead, you need another property such as:

```
Public Property SelectedAuthRoles As List(Of Integer)
```

And then, use that to look up `AuthRoles` from your database with those ids, and finally add those `AuthRole`s to your `AuthRoles` property.

(My VB is pretty lacking, as I almost exclusively use C#, so I apologize if that property above isn't quite right. It should be enough to at least communicate the idea, though.)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm as comfy in C# as VB.  I've always been of the mind set that the language shouldn't matter to a proper developer ;)  That makes sense, let me give it a whirl!